# Why revolution slider are not working on mean.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I installed Mean.js and try to change 
    site\public\modules\core\views\home.client.view.html with revolution slider. I added all required js and css files in core module (with grunt)
    `revolution-slider.css
    layerslider.css
    jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js
    jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js
    revolution_slider.js`
and jquery

and there is no errors in chrome console but nothing happen. just template without slider.
Maybe i can't put slider within Angular controller?

```
<section data-ng-controller="HomeController">
<!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
        <div class="slider fullwidthbanner-container roundedcorners">
            <div class="fullwidthbanner" data-height="650">
                <ul class="hide">
                    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                    <li data-transition="fade" 
                        data-slotamount="14"  
                        data-masterspeed="300" 
                        data-delay="10000">
                        <!-- COVER IMAGE -->
                        <img src="/modules/core/img/sliders/1x1.png" data-lazyload="/modules/core/img/sliders/bg4.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" />
                        <div class="tp-caption modern_medium_fat lfl stl"
                             data-x="60"
                             data-y="300"
                             data-speed="300"
                             data-start="500"
                             data-easing="easeOutExpo">
                DO YOU NEED A NEW
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                    <li data-transition="fade" 
                        data-slotamount="7"  
                        data-masterspeed="300" 
                        data-link="http://www.stepofweb.com/" 
                        data-target="_blank" 
                        data-saveperformance="off" >
                        <img src="/modules/core/img/sliders/1x1.png" 
                             data-lazyload="/modules/core/img/sliders/slide-b-1.png" 
                             alt="" 
                             data-bgfit="cover" 
                             data-bgposition="center bottom" 
                             data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need animation like this http://theme.stepofweb.com/Epona/v1.1/HTML/feature-header-transparent.html

Comment: did you get a soludtion for this implementation